# PHP can't see any files on a mounted filesystem

Tags: php, linux

I have a new file server (FilServerB) that I have had up and running for a few months.  I've been moving all my processing servers over to use FileServerB for their PHP code.  I recently found a server (server name is susan) that I had missed, and it was still connecting to the old file server (FileServerA).  When I mounted FileServerB on susan, none of the code would run on it anymore.  In ssh, when I go to a directory with PHP code in it, and run "php cleanISL.php", it says this:

```
Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'cleanISL.php' (include_path='.:/local/online/live/common:/local/online/pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

If I create a new php file on the local filesystem, it runs just fine.  If I try an `is_file` or `is_directory` for a file or directory that I know exists on the mounted filesystem, it always returns false.  However, I can `glob` directories, and it shows the files in there just fine.

I've tried changing (and removing completely) my include_path, I've tried going back to the old file server (which works), and then unmounting the old one and mounting the new one the exact same way (still doesn't work), and a few other things.  I can't tell if the issue is with PHP, or somehow with the way the server is mounted, or something else.  I've made sure SELINUX is disabled.  The issue seems to be only affecting PHP, and only when I mount the new FileServerB, and only on this particular server (susan).  But I'm baffled at what could be causing it or how to fix it.

Also, I have mounts to other servers (for data/media) on this same server (susan), and those work just fine, ie, PHP can see and read files on those mounts too.

**UPDATE 1, strace info**

This is the relevant line of the strace on a failed is_dir:

```
stat64("/online/live/tools/test/fixes/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
```

And this is the output of a stat command on the same dir:

```
  File: `/online/live/tools/test/fixes/'
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 32768  directory
Device: 18h/24d Inode: 11815229588  Links: 3
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 1004/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: ( 1010/ UNKNOWN)
Access: 2016-07-06 07:28:46.606024801 -0600
Modify: 2016-06-24 16:23:42.206547505 -0600
Change: 2016-06-24 16:23:42.206547505 -0600
```

And this is a namei -m result:

```
 dr-xr-xr-x /
 lrwxrwxrwx online -> /mnt/code/online/
   dr-xr-xr-x /
   drwxr-xr-x mnt
   drwxr-xr-x code
   drwxr-xr-x online
 drwxrwxrwx live
 drwxrwxr-x tools
 drwxrwxr-x test
 drwxrwxr-x fixes
```

Comment: did you mount with fstab or mount? if you did, you should be able to ls into the direcotory

Comment: I've used both, and for both I can see the directories and files just fine from the command line.  It's just PHP that can't see them.

Comment: what is the owner of the dir /online/live/tools/test/fixes/ ?

Comment: from apache do this: <Directory /online/live/tools/test/fixes/>
    Allow from All
<Directory>, enter the directory on there and restart apache. If that works, create a short symbolic link. Make sure it's between the virtualhost entry.

Comment: this is going to give your apache permission to share the webdir; you need to add that to apache, so apache can dispatch permission to php to serve the files from php ? makes sense? php can't access directories that apache doesn't map from the httpd.conf

Comment: @unixmiah I'm not running apache on the server in question (susan).  The owner is UID 1004, which doesn't exist on susan.  But it's not a rights issue, as far as I can tell, since from the command line I can see the file and it's contents, but PHP can't.

Comment: Command line and PHP is different; PHP lays on top of Linux, which still needs a user when you execute PHP it looks for a user.

Comment: Find the php user, run shell_exec( 'whoami' ) with in php file and make sure that user has the rights to the folder.

Comment: When I execute PHP from the command line, it is me (the logged in user) that it executes as.  I don't really understand what you're trying to say here.  I did create a whoami.php file with the contents "<?php echo shell_exec('whoami');" and it outputted (as expected) my username.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116731/discussion-between-unixmiah-and-rob).